# Excel 2010 - Macro Setlink to specific columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

How do I set this macro to apply to all of column A from all of Column G:

This works, but I want to apply it to all active rows in column A. This takes the hyperlinks in column G and applies it to the exact same row in column A.

```
Sub setlink()

Dim r1 As Range
Dim r2 As Range
Set r1 = Sheet2.Range("a2")
Set r2 = Sheet2.Range("G2")
Sheet2.Hyperlinks.Add r1, r2.Value

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured out a solution using this code. I put my data in columns A and B, so this code creates a hyper link in column C using display text in A and URL in column B.

```
Sub MakeHyperlinksUsingArray()
    Dim vArray As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With Sheets("Backup")
        vArray = .Range("A2:B" & _
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(vArray, 1)
            .Hyperlinks.Add _
                Anchor:=.Cells(i + 1, "C"), _
                Address:=vArray(i, 2), _
                TextToDisplay:=vArray(i, 1)
        Next i
    End With 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple and just copy the column.

```
Columns("G").Copy
Columns("A").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

This will quickly and easily copy column G to column A, as is, including hyperlinks.

Comment: That doesn't seem to retain the text from column A. I want to retain it as the displayed text while using the URL in column G.

Comment: Essentially =hyperlink() would've worked, but it is limited by character so I can not use that.

Comment: Your question was not clear that there was existing data in column A. I was misled by your statement "*apply to all of column A from all of Column G*". That sounds like a copy. Please clarify your question so we can try to help you.

Comment: Sorry about that. Example, A2 = Google. G2 = www.google.com. I want to create a hyperlink in A2, using the URL from G2. The display text should remain the same as A2.

Comment: I want to apply the same rule to every row in columns A and G

Comment: For the sake of others who will see this, please add the details of your comments to the actual question above. This will make your question and answer helpful to those who may also search to do the same.